# Can I change where the x-axis intersects the y-axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some index data as a bar chart. I'd like to emphasise the "above index" and "below index"-ness of the numbers by forcing the x-axis to cross at 100 (such that a value of 80 would appear as a -20 bar.)

This is part of a much longer process, so it's hard to share data usefully. Here, though, is some bodge-y code that illustrates the problem (and the beginnings of my solution):

```
df <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"),c(118,80,65))
names(df) <- c("label","index")

my.plot <- ggplot(df,aes(label,index))
my.plot + geom_bar()

df$adjusted <- as.numeric(lapply(df$index,function(x) x-100))

my.plot2 <- ggplot(df,aes(label,adjusted))
my.plot2 + geom_bar()
```

I can, of course, change my index calculation to read: `(value.new/value.old)*100-100` then title the chart appropriately (something like "xxx relative to index") but this seems clumsy.

So, too, does the approach I've been testing (to run the simple calculation above, then re-label the y-axis.) Is that *really* the best solution?

No doubt someone's going to tell me that this sort of axis manipulation is frowned upon. If this is the case, please could they point me in the direction of an explanation? At least then I'll have learned something.

Comment: Could you provde a reproducible example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27808635/937932) for how to achieve this by hacking the y-axis labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate system of you plot has the x-axis and the y-axis crossing at (0,0). This is just the way you define your coordinate system. You can of course draw a horizontal line at (x = 100), but to call this is x-axis is false.

What you already proposed is to redefine your coordinate system by transforming the data. Whether or not this transformation is appropriate is easier to answer with a reproducible example from your side.

Comment: That's interesting -- and thank you for the clear explanation. It's a fairly common chart to use in marketing presentations when presenting information about audiences (and my previous tool of choice, Excel, readily allows me to choose where the "Horizontal axis crosses at:".)

Our purpose is generally to show how groups of people are more or less likely than index to agree with certain statements. Clearly a black line would achieve this -- I wonder whether it would also be more "honest"?

Comment: @mediaczar Excel isn't really the benchmark for good statistical research and visualization :).

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't directly answer you question, but instead of missing about with the x-axis, why not make a single grid line a bit thicker? For example,

```
dd = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))
g = ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
g + geom_hline(yintercept=0.2, colour="white", lwd=3)
```

[image]

Or as Paul suggested, with a black line and some text:

```
    g + geom_hline(yintercept=0.2, colour="black", lwd=3) + 
        annotate("text", x = 2, y = 0.22, label = "Reference")
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would be more clear to draw a solid black there, and maybe add a piece of text that says "reference" or such.