# How to plot deviation from mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

In R I have created a simple matrix of one column yielding a list of numbers with a set mean and a given standard deviation.

```
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
r <- rnorm2(100,4,1)
```

I now would like to plot how these numbers differ from the mean. I can do this in Excel as shown below:

[image]

But I would like to use `ggplot2` to create a graph in R. in the Excel graph I have cheated by using a line graph but if I could do this as columns it would be better. I have tried using a scatter plot but I cant work out how to turn this into deviations from the mean.

Comment: what do you mean by "do this as columns" ?

Comment: As in rather than joining each point to the one previous and after it as you have in a line graph (for a zoomed in version see the answer below) but have a line joining each point to the mean value. Basically a bar chart with narrow bars centered around the mean rather than zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
set.seed(101)
r <- rnorm2(100,4,1)
x <- seq_along(r)  ## sets up a vector from 1 to length(r)
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic preferences
plot(x, r, col = "green", pch=16) ## draws the points
## if you don't want points at all, use 
##    plot(x, r, type="n")  
## to set up the axes without drawing anything inside them
segments(x0=x, y0=4, x1=x, y1=r, col="green") ## connects them to the mean line
abline(h=4)
```

If you were plotting around 0 you could do this automatically with `type="h"`:

```
plot(x,r-4,type="h", col="green")
```

To do this in `ggplot2`:

```
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw()) ## my cosmetic preferences
ggplot(data.frame(x,r))+
    geom_segment(aes(x=x,xend=x,y=mean(r),yend=r),colour="green")+
    geom_hline(yintercept=mean(r))
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. Do you know how I could remove the circle? Theres no option with pch that I can see that would leave just the columns and have a transparent point

Comment: how about `type="n"` (and leave out `pch` entirely)?

Comment: Could also probably add `+ geom_abline(intercept = 4, slope = 0)` to the end

Comment: Thats pretty much perfect, last question: Would I be able to change the width of the segments(columns) so its one continuous mass of color rather than with whitespace, purely for aesthetic reasons. Thank you for all your help

Comment: include `width=4` (or whatever) after `colour="green"` in the `ggplot` specification, or specify `lwd=4` (or whatever) in the base plot (I think -- haven't tested)

Comment: `width = 4` would have to be manually adjusted for the size of the graph and the number of categories.  How about `geom_bar(aes(x, r - mean(r)), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "green")` for a more automatic version?

Answer (score 3):

Ben's answer using ggplot2 works great, but if you don't want to manually adjust the line width, you could do this:

```
# Half of Ben's data
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
set.seed(101)
r <- rnorm2(50,4,1)
x <- seq_along(r)  ## sets up a vector from 1 to length(r)

# New variable for the difference between each value and the mean
value <- r - mean(r)

ggplot(data.frame(x, value)) +
  # geom_bar anchors each bar at zero (which is the mean minus the mean)
  geom_bar(aes(x, value), stat = "identity"
           , position = "dodge", fill = "green") +
  # but you can change the y-axis labels with a function, to add the mean back on
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) {x + mean(r)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in base R it's quite simple, just do

```
plot(r, col = "green", type = "l")
abline(4, 0)
```

[image]

You also tagged `ggplot2`, so in that case it will be a bit more complicated, because `ggplot` requires creating a data frame and then melting it.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(data.frame(x = 1:100, mean = 4, r = r), 1)
ggplot(df, aes(x, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: This is close but I am preferentially looking for a column graph, as shown in the below answer rather than a line graph

Comment: I guess, for simplicity, you could just scale it and use `type = "h"`, something quick like `plot(r - 4, col = "green", type = "h") ; abline(0, 0)`